# SQL: Error when trying to output all the names which belong to a category that satisfies a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following two tables:

Shop:

```
Name       |  Country
Pharmacy      Japan
Green Vine    Italy
Red Palace    Morocco
La Pizza      Italy
Nature Shop   Japan
Medical 100   Japan
Sports Life   Japan
Athletics     Japan
```

Info:

```
Name      |    Category    |    Price
Pharmacy       Health           Cheap
Green Vine     Dining           Medium
Red Palace     Dining           Expensive
La Pizza       Dining           Cheap
Nature Shop    Health           Medium
Health 100     Health           Expensive
Sports Life    Sport            Cheap
Athletics      Sport            Expensive
```

I am trying to write a query that outputs all the Names that belong to a category where all the countries are Japan (e.g. all the stores in the Health and Sport category are in Japan). E.g. the output would be:

```
Name        |   Country    |    Category
Pharmacy        Japan           Health
Nature Shop     Japan           Health
Medical 100     Japan           Health
Sports Life     Japan           Sport
Athletics       Japan           Sport
```

I have the following code:

```
select t1.Code, t1.Country, x.Category
from Shop t1
inner join (select t2.Category, t3.Country
            from Info t2, Shop t3
            group by t2.Category
            having max(t3.Country) = min(t3.Country)
            and max(t3.Country) = 'Japan') x
            on x.Name = t1.Name;
```

However, when I execute the query, I get the following error:

> ERROR: column "t3.country" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 3: inner join (select t2.Category, t3.Country

I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to fix it. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using sub query but the result require can be get by using a join

```
select shop.Country,shop.Name,info.Category from shop LEFT JOIN info on  shop.name = INFO.name where shop.country ='Japan' and info.Category in ('Health','Sport')
```